# How to read in information from a file, and store it as a string. Java

Tags: java, string, file

ive gotten this far, but this doesnt work to read in the file, thats the part im stuck on. i know that you need to use the scanner, but im not sure what im missing here. i think it needs a path to the file also, but i dont know where to put that in

```
public class string
{

public static String getInput(Scanner in) throws IOException
{



{ 
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter file");
String filename =keyboard.next(); 

File inputFile = new File(filename);
Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
String line;

while (input.hasNext())
{
line= input.nextLine();
System.out.println(line);
}
input.close();
}
if(filename.isEmpty()) 
{
    System.out.println("Sorry, there has been an error. You must enter a string! (A string is       some characters put together.) Try Again Below.");
   return getInput(in);   
}
else
{
    return filename;
}
}   



public static int getWordCount(String input)
{

String[] result = input.split(" ");
return result.length;
}     




 public static void main(String[] args)
{
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
String input = getInput(new Scanner(System.in)); 
float counter = getWordCount(input);
System.out.println("The number of words in this string  ("+input+")  are: " + counter);
Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);

}   

}
//end of code
```

Comment: Please format your code. People are unlikely to read and answer your question if you have't taken the time to present it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when doing file I/O in Java, you should properly handle all exceptions and errors that can occur.

In general, you need to open streams and resources in a [**try**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) block, catch all exceptions that happen in a [**catch**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) block and then close all resources in a [**finally**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) block. You should read up more on these [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) as well.

For using a `Scanner` object, this would look something like:

```
    String token = null;
    File file = null; 
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        file = new File("/path/to/file.txt");
        in = new Scanner(file);
        while(in.hasNext()) {
            token = in.next();
           // ...
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // if File with that pathname doesn't exist
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(in != null) {  // pay attention to NullPointerException possibility here
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

You can also use a `BufferedReader` to read a file line by line.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt"));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   // ...
}
```

With added exception handling:

```
    String line = null;
    FileReader fReader = null;
    BufferedReader bReader = null;
    try {
        fReader = new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt");
        bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
               // ...
            }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Missing file for the FileReader
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // I/O Exception for the BufferedReader
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(fReader != null) { // pay attention to NullPointerException possibility here
            try {
                fReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(bReader != null) { // pay attention to NullPointerException possibility here
            try {
                bReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

In general, use the `Scanner` for parsing a file, and use the `BufferedReader` for reading the file line by line.

There are other more advanced ways to perform reading/writing operations in Java. Check out some of them [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)